# SQL Query takes a really long time with a specific value and not others

Tags: sql, join

The query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(q."TopicId") as TotalQuestions 
FROM "Questions" q 
JOIN "QuestionScores" qs 
  ON qs."QuestionId"=q."id"
WHERE qs."version" = (SELECT "version" 
                      FROM "QuestionScores" 
                      ORDER BY "version" DESC 
                      LIMIT 1)
  AND qs."StudentId"= 105 
  AND q."status"='active' 
  AND q."TopicId" = 125 
  AND q."PassageId" IS NULL
```

This query takes almost 90 seconds.

If I change `TopicId` to 18, then it runs in a second. What could be the issue?

Comment: As written, I don't think this query does anything useful.

Comment: It should return a count

Comment: What is the purpose of the subquery?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  A count of active questions for topic 125 and student 105 that have no value for passageID but only for the LATEST version of question score?  Sample Data expected results would likely help as would an execution plan to see why 90 sec vs second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend if I were you I would consider to create some index for your columns.

Here is some information about index:

1. How to create Index: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp
2. Differences between clustered and non clustered index: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described
3. Some good explanation about it on this issue: [SQL Indexes and performance improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542895/sql-indexes-and-performance-improvement)